# How to read an input file of strings, match and change the matches in-place?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a text file with strings/filenames in separate lines, eg. `filename.txt`. There are hundreds of filenames

```
ABC123_S386_R1_001
JKL345_S441_R1_001
filename9000_S587_R1_001
```

and another text file with the string/filenames and additional data eg. `results.txt`:

```
>ABC123_S386_R1_001 
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>JKL345_S441_R1_001
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>abc7890_S387_R1_001  
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>filename9000_S587_R1_001
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

Now not all filenames in `filename.txt` are present in `results.txt`, neither are they in order. I want to insert a prefix to all the filenames from `filename.txt` to `results.txt` but not to the others.

How do I read an input file of strings, match with another file and change the matches?

Earlier I used to go about matching individual filenames with `sequence.txt`, getting their line number and used `sed` with line numbers to change either a single line or a block of lines.

My desired output would look like

```
>h-19/US/CA-ABC123_S386_R1_001 
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>h-19/US/CA-JKL345_S441_R1_001
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>abc7890_S387_R1_001  
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>h-19/US/CA-filename9000_S587_R1_001
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

where `h-19/US/CA-` is the suffix I'd like to add to all the matches.

Edit: `>` is the first character of all the strings that need to be changed, there are no characters before `>` neither are any trailing white spaces after the filename.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the relevant lines in `results.txt` do not contain whitespace after the filename, the following `awk` program will work:

```
awk -v prefix="h-19/US/CA-" 'NR==FNR{fnames[$1]; next} \
    /^>/{name=substr($0,2); if (name in fnames) {sub(/^>/, ">" prefix)} }1' filenames.txt results.txt
```

- This will first parse `filenames.txt` and then `results.txt`.
- While parsing `filenames.txt` (where `FNR`, the per-file line counter, is equal to `NR`,the global line counter) it will register all filenames (which are the only fields on the line) in an array `fnames`, but then skip execution immediately to the next line.
- While parsing `results.txt` it will check if a line starts with `>`. If so, it will check if the substring following that character (stored temporarily in `name`) is found among the "array indices" of `fnames`. If that is the case, it will use `sub()` to substitute the leading `>` with `>`+the prefix, passed to `awk` as variable `prefix` (via the `-v` directive).
- The seemingly "stray" `1` will instruct `awk` to print the current line, including all possible modifications (but only for `results.txt` since during processing of the first file we don't reach that part).

Note that `awk` by itself cannot modify files in-place, so you would need to work with a temporary file. If you have a sufficiently new version of GNU Awk (> 4.1.0), you can however use the `inplace` extension; of course, you will then need to turn the option off for the `filenames.txt` file:

```
awk -i inplace -v prefix=" ... " ' ... ' inplace=0 filenames.txt inplace=1 results.txt
```

This will turn in-place editing off for `filenames.txt` and on again for `results.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` you can collect the filenames in hold space and then for all lines in `results.txt` check for matches to filter what lines to change:

```
sed -e '1,/^$/{H;1h;d;}' -e 'G;/^>\(.*\).*\n\1\n/s_^>_>h-19/US/CA-_;P;d' filename.txt <((echo)) results.txt
```

- You see that I pass an empty line with `<((echo))` between the files, so `1,/^$/` addresses all lines of the first file (and the empty line)
- Those lines get appended to hold space and then deleted with `H;1h;d` (`1h` avoids starting the hold space with a newline)
- `G` appends the hold space to all lines of `result.txt` and `/^>\(.*\).*\n\1\n/` matches those lines that start with `>` and a string which is a filename (enclosed in newlines in the hold space)
- `s_^>_>h-19/US/CA-_` does the replacement for those line
- `P;d` prints just the first line without the appended junk. You could do `s/\n.*//` instead

Answer (score 1):

Use `perl` for inplace edits to input file:

```
pfx='h-19/US/CA-' \
perl -pi -e '
  BEGIN { %h = map { tr/\n//dr => $ENV{pfx}} <STDIN>}
  s/^>\K(?=(.*))/$h{$1}/;
' results.txt < filename.txt
```